# Checkbox calculation not working

Tags: javascript, checkbox, calculated-field, subtotal

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function() {
    var tot = 0;
    $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
      tot += +(this.value);
    });
    $("#result").text("Total = " + tot);
    $('#CRCGCA').val("Total = " + tot)
  });
});
```

```html
<p>Gift Certificate Amount (check one or more)
  <br />
  <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap GRCGA"><span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-checkbox wpcf7-validates-as-required Multiple radio-vertical" id="GRCGA"><span class="wpcf7-list-item first"><label><input type="checkbox" name="GRCGA[]" value="$10.00 Gift Card" />&nbsp;<span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">$10.00 Gift Card</span>
  </label>
  </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item"><label><input type="checkbox" name="GRCGA[]" value="$20.00 Gift Card" />&nbsp;<span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">$20.00 Gift Card</span>
  </label>
  </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item"><label><input type="checkbox" name="GRCGA[]" value="$25.00 Gift Card" />&nbsp;<span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">$25.00 Gift Card</span>
  </label>
  </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item"><label><input type="checkbox" name="GRCGA[]" value="$40.00 Gift Card" />&nbsp;<span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">$40.00 Gift Card</span>
  </label>
  </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item"><label><input type="checkbox" name="GRCGA[]" value="$100.00 Gift Card" />&nbsp;<span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">$100.00 Gift Card</span>
  </label>
  </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item"><label><input type="checkbox" name="GRCGA[]" value="$200.00 Gift Card" />&nbsp;<span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">$200.00 Gift Card</span>
  </label>
  </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item"><label><input type="checkbox" name="GRCGA[]" value="$400.00 Gift Card" />&nbsp;<span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">$400.00 Gift Card</span>
  </label>
  </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item last"><label><input type="checkbox" name="GRCGA[]" value="$500.00 Gift Card" />&nbsp;<span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">$500.00 Gift Card</span>
  </label>
  </span>
  </span>
  </span>
</p>
<p>Gift Card Amount: <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap CRCGCA"><input type="text" name="CRCGCA" value="" size="8" maxlength="8" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" id="CRCGCA" aria-invalid="false" /></span>
</p>

<p id="result"></p>
```

I am having a problem calculating the total of the checkbox group ( this check box set is multi selectable ( can have one or more picked)  I also like to have the total copied to the text box called gift card amount.

HTML:

```
<p>
    Gift Certificate Amount (check one or more)<br />
    [checkbox* GRCGA id:GRCGA class:Multiple use_label_element class:radio-vertical "$10.00 Gift Card " "$20.00 Gift Card " "$25.00 Gift Card " "$40.00 Gift Card " "$100.00 Gift Card " "$200.00 Gift Card " "$400.00 Gift Card " "$500.00 Gift Card"] 
</p>   
Gift Card Amount: [text CRCGCA 8/8 id:CRCGCA]
<p id="result"></p>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function() {
        var tot = 0;

        $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
            tot += +(this.value);
        });

        $("#result").text("Total = " + tot);
        $('#CRCGCA').val("Total = " + tot)         
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you add jsfiddle?

Comment: Please show the (relevant, minimal) HTML. Possibly also a Stack Snippet, to demonstrate what your code does (in the question editor, the button with a pencil next to the image icon, above the textarea).

Comment: Thank you for letting me know how to do the little snippet I never new about it. I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your checkboxes have values like `$25.00 Gift Card`. You need to change it to a number, e.g. `25`.

If you insist on using your current markup you could get the actual number using

```
var val = this.value.substr(1).split(' ')[0];
tot += +(val);
```

Though someone who's good at regexp can probably figure out something prettier.

Comment: is there a way to allow values

Comment: Yes, using JS you can convert the final output amount to $.

Comment: @Annie You mean keep the values as they are, but still calculate a sum?

Comment: take away the second input line and add that

Comment: figured out the $ sign

Answer (score 0):

One approach, using `String.prototype.match()` and `Array.prototype.reduce()`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function() {
    // concatenating a currency symbol to the result of mapping the checked checkboxes:
    var total = '$' + $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function(){
      // matching one-or-more numbers ('\d+') followed by a (literal) period ('\.')
      // followed by one-or-more numbers:
      var n = this.value.match(/\d+\.\d+/);
      // if there was a match (and 'n' is therefore not-null), and has a length,
      // we parseFloat that matched number string, otherwise we return 0:
      return n && n.length ? parseFloat(n[0]) : 0;
    // get() converts the 'map' into an array:
    }).get()
    // reduce() sums together the array-elements ('a + b'):
    .reduce(function (a, b) {
      return a + b;
      // '0' is the supplied starting value for reduce():
    }, 0)
    // toFixed(2) converts the number to a string, with two decimal places:
    .toFixed(2);

    $("#result").text("Total = " + total);
    $('#CRCGCA').val("Total = " + total)
  });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function() {
    var total = '$' + $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function(){
      var n = this.value.match(/\d+\.\d+/);
      return n && n.length ? parseFloat(n[0]) : 0;
    }).get().reduce(function (a, b) {
      return a + b;
    }, 0).toFixed(2);
    $("#result").text("Total = " + total);
    $('#CRCGCA').val("Total = " + total)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Gift Certificate Amount (check one or more)
  <br />
  <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap GRCGA"><span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-checkbox wpcf7-validates-as-required Multiple radio-vertical" id="GRCGA"><span class="wpcf7-list-item first"><label><input type="checkbox" name="GRCGA[]" value="$10.00 Gift Card" />&nbsp;<span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">$10.0 Gift Card</span>
  </label>
  </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item"><label><input type="checkbox" name="GRCGA[]" value="$20.00 Gift Card" />&nbsp;<span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">$20.00 Gift Card</span>
  </label>
  </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item"><label><input type="checkbox" name="GRCGA[]" value="$25.00 Gift Card" />&nbsp;<span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">$25.00 Gift Card</span>
  </label>
  </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item"><label><input type="checkbox" name="GRCGA[]" value="$40.00 Gift Card" />&nbsp;<span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">$40.00 Gift Card</span>
  </label>
  </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item"><label><input type="checkbox" name="GRCGA[]" value="$100.00 Gift Card" />&nbsp;<span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">$100.00 Gift Card</span>
  </label>
  </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item"><label><input type="checkbox" name="GRCGA[]" value="$200.00 Gift Card" />&nbsp;<span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">$200.00 Gift Card</span>
  </label>
  </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item"><label><input type="checkbox" name="GRCGA[]" value="$400.00 Gift Card" />&nbsp;<span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">$400.00 Gift Card</span>
  </label>
  </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item last"><label><input type="checkbox" name="GRCGA[]" value="$500.00 Gift Card" />&nbsp;<span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">$500.00 Gift Card</span>
  </label>
  </span>
  </span>
  </span>
</p>
<p>Gift Card Amount: <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap CRCGCA"><input type="text" name="CRCGCA" value="" size="8" maxlength="8" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" id="CRCGCA" aria-invalid="false" /></span>
</p>

<p id="result"></p>
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).
  - [JavaScript regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
  - [`Number.prototype.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed).
  - [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).
  - [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).
- jQuery:

  - [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
  - [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).
  - [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).
  - [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).